# Counting number of matched words

Tags: php, mysql

i have two tables, with data populated in this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64a4d/35/0)

right now, I have a query that looks like the below, when i search for "George Tabuki Street Fighter Miley Cyrus", I have the php `explode` the search string and dynamically build the query by adding the `+ CASE WHEN ... END`

```
SELECT id,word,LEFT(description,100)as description, 
             IFNULL((SELECT sum(vote)
                     FROM vote v
                     WHERE v.definition_id = d.id),0) as votecount,
         0
    + CASE WHEN LOCATE('George',CONCAT(word,description,`usage`))>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    + CASE WHEN LOCATE('Tabuki',CONCAT(word,description,`usage`))>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    + CASE WHEN LOCATE('Street',CONCAT(word,description,`usage`))>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    + CASE WHEN LOCATE('Fighter',CONCAT(word,description,`usage`))>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    + CASE WHEN LOCATE('Miley',CONCAT(word,description,`usage`))>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    + CASE WHEN LOCATE('Cyrus',CONCAT(word,description,`usage`))>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
as `match`
FROM definition d
HAVING `match` > 0
ORDER BY `match` DESC,votecount DESC
```

The query above returns exactly what i want.

Question: is there a better way, or is there a function in mySQL that returns a count of number of matched words?

### Updated:

I have found a better way, well not better way but it returns a count of occurences of matching terms

```
SELECT id,word,LEFT(description,100)as description, 
             IFNULL((SELECT sum(vote)
                     FROM vote v
                     WHERE v.definition_id = d.id),0) as votecount,
         0
        + IFNULL(ROUND((LENGTH(CONCAT(word,description,`usage`,`by`)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(CONCAT(word,description,`usage`,`by`), 'George', '')))/LENGTH('George')),0)
        + IFNULL(ROUND((LENGTH(CONCAT(word,description,`usage`,`by`)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(CONCAT(word,description,`usage`,`by`), 'Tabuki', '')))/LENGTH('Tabuki')),0)
        + IFNULL(ROUND((LENGTH(CONCAT(word,description,`usage`,`by`)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(CONCAT(word,description,`usage`,`by`), 'Street', '')))/LENGTH('Street')),0)
        + IFNULL(ROUND((LENGTH(CONCAT(word,description,`usage`,`by`)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(CONCAT(word,description,`usage`,`by`), 'Fighter', '')))/LENGTH('Fighter')),0)
        + IFNULL(ROUND((LENGTH(CONCAT(word,description,`usage`,`by`)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(CONCAT(word,description,`usage`,`by`), 'Miley', '')))/LENGTH('Miley')),0)
        + IFNULL(ROUND((LENGTH(CONCAT(word,description,`usage`,`by`)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(CONCAT(word,description,`usage`,`by`), 'Cyrus', '')))/LENGTH('Cyrus')),0)
as `match`
FROM definition d
HAVING `match` > 0
ORDER BY `match` DESC,votecount DESC;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it is a better way but this is how I would do it:

```
SELECT d.id, d.word, LEFT(d.description, 100) description,
  COALESCE(sum(v.vote), 0) votecount,
    (CONCAT(word, description, `usage`) LIKE '%George%')
  + (CONCAT(word, description, `usage`) LIKE '%Tabuki%')
  + (CONCAT(word, description, `usage`) LIKE '%Street%')
  + (CONCAT(word, description, `usage`) LIKE '%Fighter%')
  + (CONCAT(word, description, `usage`) LIKE '%Miley%')
  + (CONCAT(word, description, `usage`) LIKE '%Cyrus%') `match`
FROM definition d
LEFT JOIN vote v ON v.definition_id = d.id
GROUP BY d.id
HAVING `match` > 0
ORDER BY `match` DESC, votecount DESC
```

If the strings are long enough maybe the repeated concatenation might take more time than creating a derived table (unlikely, but it's worth giving it a try):

```
SELECT id, word, description, votecount,
    (fullDesc LIKE '%George%')
  + (fullDesc LIKE '%Tabuki%')
  + (fullDesc LIKE '%Street%')
  + (fullDesc LIKE '%Fighter%')
  + (fullDesc LIKE '%Miley%')
  + (fullDesc LIKE '%Cyrus%') `match`
FROM (
  SELECT d.id, d.word, LEFT(d.description, 100) description,
    COALESCE(sum(vote), 0) votecount, CONCAT(word, description, `usage`) fullDesc
  FROM definition d
  LEFT JOIN vote v ON v.definition_id = d.id
  GROUP BY d.id
) s
HAVING `match` > 0
ORDER BY `match` DESC, votecount DESC
```

Comment: thank you, I ended up using  your first suggestion. read somewhere that LIKE is a little faster and I like that LIKE when bracketed returns 1