# Search MySQL text column with array of words and sort according to amount of matches

Tags: php, mysql, sql, innodb

How do I retrieve records from a MySQL table (Innodb) with results sorted according to how many sub-strings a record's two columns might contain.

I'm searching for words in bodies of texts contained within two different columns. So the word might exist and it might have unknown text in front or behind it.

Currently my PHP code creates a query that searches two columns (contains text) with a varying amount of different sub-strings.

See simplified example:

```
$string = "";

foreach $array_of_words as $word) {
    $string = $string . " column_one LIKE '% $word%' OR column_two LIKE '% $word%' OR ";
}

$string = substr ( $string, 0, - 3 );

$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_maintable WHERE (" . $string . ") LIMIT 5";
```

This works fairly well even though it is not exactly what I would like, however the biggest issue with the above code is that it's resource intensive (7 seconds to complete a query against a 100k database).

I have taken a look at natural language searches (to a certain extent), but the documentation hasn't given me a clear definitive method I can use, and the MYSQL version (5.5.44) of the MySQL server in question does not have that option for InnoDB. I will however upgrade if that is the only option.

Comment: Have you tried full text search query?

Comment: Have you tried using:  ` AND MATCH(columnName) AGAINST ('textString' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0`  substituting 'columnName' and 'textString'..

Comment: I have tried full text searches, however that option is only available for InnoDB 5.6 and up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could use [MySQL's fulltext search](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20320723/933633) and order by relevancy.

You need to alter your table to add fulltext search index.

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl_maintable` ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `SEARCH`(`columnName`);
```

And then run a query like this:

```
SELECT *, MATCH(columnName) AGAINST ('word1 word2 word3 word4' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance
FROM tbl_maintable WHERE
MATCH (columnName) AGAINST ('word1 word2 word3 word4' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

There are other methods to achieve this but, without Fulltext indexing, will perform very poorly, as relational databases weren't really built for this kind of work.

Take a look at this answer for a non-fulltext option but will cost in performance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20320723/933633

Comment: That would be great, but full text search are only available for InnoDB 5.6 and up. Seem like I need to upgrade.

Comment: @BarryBrian: Have a look at my edit. I've added an answer from another question that counts matched words in a field. It will perform badly, no doubt, but may help you until you upgrade MySQL and use Fulltext indexing.

Comment: I ended up upgrading MySQL and using your query, works like a charm. Thanks